# chart.js Adding Percantage Sign on Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

```
    var dmgchartt = document.getElementById("dmgchart");
    new Chart(dmgchartt, {
    type: "radar",
    data: radarChartData0,
    options: {
             tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value + ' %' %>",
              scale: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Title'
        }
    }
});
```

It just shows the value without percentage sign. I tried to add percentage sign after value on tooltip but it didn't work. Also how can i choose if tooltip is multi or single? I have 2 datasets.

[image: tooltip]

Comment: You use Chart.js 2.0, right? Could you please provide a jsfiddle? `tooltipTemplate` is for Chart.js 1.0. In Chart.js 2.0 you use `options.tooltips.callbacks.labels`.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using Chart.js 2.0 as suggested by @xnakos in the comments you have to use `options.tooltips.callbacks.label`

```
 var dmgchartt = document.getElementById("dmgchart");
 new Chart(dmgchartt, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '%';
                    }
                }
            },
          scale: {
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        },
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Title'
    }

    }
    });
```

Comment: If you want the label and the value: `label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                    var idx = tooltipItem['index'];
                                    var caption = data.labels[idx];
                                    var captionValue = data['datasets'][0]['data'][idx];
                                    return  caption+':'+captionValue+'%';
                                }`

Answer (score 3):

Mentioned solutions did not work for me. It throws away default label handling (data.labels/dataset labels) and you must format string again. If you need only to add percentage sign, you can simply use default callback `Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label` as [doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) says. So for v2.x it will be:

```
 options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label(tooltipItem, data) + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac's answer is super close, but I had an issue when implementing it as:

```
return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '%';
```

instead use tooltipItem['datasetIndex'] to allow the correct display to show on hover. Otherwise it will only show the first array values no matter what is hovered on. My implemented solution below:

```
return data['datasets'][tooltipItem['datasetIndex']]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '%';
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try to put the `%` outside the value block.
I use it like this:

```
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= label %>: <%= value %>%",
```

Comment: I tried your `<%= value + ' %' %>` and it does work for me too.
There must be something to do with the if part.